# Xamarin.iOS can convert latlong to address with error com.google.HTTPStatus error 400

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I need to convert my Latitude and longitude to address to extract so data from it

here is my method but this fail with error `{The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)}`

```
void ConvertLatLong(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            try
            {
                Geocoder geocoder;
                CLLocationCoordinate2D location = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude, longitude);

                geocoder = new Geocoder();

                geocoder.ReverseGeocodeCord(location ,(response, error) => {

                    if (error != null) return;

                    var addresses = response.Results;
                    if (addresses != null && addresses.Length > 1)
                    {
                      Address selectedAddress = addresses[1];
                      if (selectedAddress.AdministrativeArea != null)
                      {
                            var citySelected = citiesLookupResult.Find(c => (selectedAddress.AdministrativeArea.Contains(c.NameEn)));
                            chooseCity.Text = citySelected.NameEn;
                      }
                    }

                });


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

my tries to fix this issue

**First** I make sure that my bundle name is matched between google console and my application

**Second**  make sure I set my E-mail , app name under Credential --> oAuth consent screen

any one could help me with my issue

[image]

Comment: make sure "enable GoogleMap SDK for iOS"

Comment: did you register api key for GMSServices  in appdelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions

1. Enable GoogleMap SDK for iOS [Here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/maps_ios_backend/overview?project=)
2. Register Api key for GMSServices in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
3. Check that your API key is valid for your bundle id on console.developer.google.com.